# City Bikes vs E-Bikes with baby trailer

Tags: trailer, city, electric-bike

We moved the Denmark where the bicycle roads are extremely good and there are only a few hills.

Our house a bit far from the center so my wife and I will need to ride like 8-9km to city center quite often. And most closest market is like 1-2km far from us. And most important we have our daughter who is 11 months now.

I am looking for a bike so far this [site](http://centurycycles.com/buyers-guides/bicycle-types-how-to-pick-the-best-bike-for-you-pg9.htm) makes most sense to since I don't have any experience with bikes. And it seems City bikes fits me(and my wife) most.

But I am using a road bike(similar to city bike) now I have some problems like;

- Just cycling 6km every day and back. I am being tired very much and extremely slow(where google say 20 mins it takes 40 mins  ).
- Even there are not many I am having problems with hills.
- I expect everything will be much more harder when I add the baby trailer.

So my questions are,

1- Should I prefer an E-bike over a city bike because the problems I
   listed?

2- Is it possible to mount a baby trailer to an E-bike?

---

Comment: It sounds from your question like you've decided on a trailer. We've had a few questions here discussing the relative merits of trailers vs. seats mounted on the bike itself, which might interest you if your decision isn't final. In particular, a rear seat is a lot less extra resistance than a trailer (I have both).

Comment: Example questions you might find helpful: [how young is too young](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/9622/babies-on-bakfietsen-how-young-is-too-young), [Baby Transportation Safety Statistics](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/15165/baby-transportation-safety-statistics) and [ride with toddler](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/44391/what-type-of-bike-i-should-buy-if-i-need-to-ride-with-a-toddler). I searched for "child" in the end, and got better results.

Comment: Also, going slower than google suggests makes me wonder whether there's something wrong. If you're getting overtaken by everyone else it would be worth asking a bike shop whether it's your bike (tyres pumped up, brakes not rubbing, you know how to use the gears, etc), and maybe your doctor whether it's you. Are you really fat? Or is your bike really badly maintained?

Comment: Thanks guys a lot "ride with toddler" thread really helps.  Now I am using Hotel's free bike so it look horrible and rusty but I don't want to spend time on it a lot.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, a city bike is a **style** of bicycle with sit up and beg styling, generally a single gear or internal gear hub with chainguard (although derailleurs do exist), full fenders, and a step through design. They are also often very solidly built which is a euphemism for heavy.

An electric assist can be added to any style of bicycle: city, folding, mtb, road, touring, etc.

So if you like the city bike styling, you should be able to find an electric assist city bike. Or road ebike. Whatever you like. Note that Europe restricts motor output and top speeds, so it's really best to think of it as electric **assist**.

Second, you should be able to add a trailer to most electric bikes but you might need the bike shop's help. For example, I have an electric assist folding bike and drag a trailer that is the same design as child trailers and uses the same hub-mounted hookup mechanism. Unfortunately, the rear hub axle of my electric assist is much thicker (12mm) than the hub axle of standard bikes so I had the option of either:

- drilling out the trailer mount adapter with a bigger hole so it could fit the larger ebike axle
- using an alternate chainstay / seat stay style mount
- using one of the pannier / rack holes  on the rear dropout

I ended up with the third option as it was the easiest. All these should be doable in conversation with your bike shop. Also, since you are likely buying a new child carrier, you have two other options:

- Bicycle mounted child seat - either in front of you or behind you
- trailer that attaches to the seat stem (thx Willeke)

Comment: Spot on. Though there are plenty of city type bikes with derailleur gears and all (even if they don't meet a strict definition). My wife's e-bike is one. I doubt it would be easy to fit a trailer on the axle of that bike so it's really something to look at case-by-case.

Comment: @ChrisH thx. So noted!

Comment: Not all child carriers are hub mounted, many I see in the Netherlands are attached to the seat posts, over the back carrier. This kind can be attached to bikes which can not have a hub based one.

Comment: Thx Willeke, added

Answer (score 2):

I love RoboKaren's answer. Just to add to it here's what I've learned biking with a trailer past two years.

I feel your pain and the minute you solve it you will bike everywhere. 
My set today is this: folding electric bike + kids' trailer.

[image]

I had the same problem as you. Here's chronological list of purchases I've made and why:

1. [Croozer trailer](http://croozer.info/models/croozer-kid-plus/croozer-kid-plus-for-2-detail/) for my two boys.
2. I attached it to my daily-driver '60s single-speed road bike
3. Trying to accelerate I realised I need gears:) Trying to slow down I realised I need modern brakes :)
4. So I bought a new MTB with disk breaks and 27.5" inch wheels
5. I've sold it after a year and changed to the pictured electrically assisted folding bike with 20" inch wheels.

I love every minute of it. My real world range is just shy of 40km when loaded. I mostly bike to and from shops, kindergarten, friends and family, etc. But if I ever run out range I'll just purchase another battery.

I've also run into a problem mentioned by RoboKaren about a different hub size. I've just drilled a bigger hole but it's a risky operation without a vise and a drill press. Ask any bike/car shop and they'll probably do it for you no problem.

One word on the trailer: awesome.

One sentence on the e-bike: you'll be overtaking everyone else *while* pulling a trailer :)

Comment: I have the exact same ebike. :)

Comment: It's awesome, isn't it? What brand is yours, also EcoBike?